# Python multiple watermarks at random locations

Tags: python

I have a `14 x 10` logo and I would like to use it as a watermaker when a user uploads a picture. The uploaded picture is either a `png` or a `jpeg` of at least `250 x 250`. What would be the most efficient way to cover the uploaded image with the logo at random locations?